# Pine-Script: Alert me when price changes by x in y time interval

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

what I am trying to do is a script that will alert me about quick and big price moves, for example:

when BTC price drop (between max and min of a candle) more than 100pips in 5 minutes or less, notify me.

I checked the documentation, but as I am not very experienced programmer I am stuck. Do you folks have any tips how should I approach this?

I tried standard price alerts but they only allows me to setup an alert on specific price. I am not interested of price itself, but it's movement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ta.lowest()` and `ta.highest()` functions to get the lowest and highest prices within your defined lookback period. Then calculate the difference between those in pips and trigger your alerts.

If you want to do it for the current candle, just use `low` and `high`.

Use below to get the pip size:

```
syminfo.mintick * (syminfo.type == "forex" ? 10 : 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that was very helpful.

What I have now and it seems to work:

````
study("Price Move Alert", overlay=false)


pipThreshold = input(50, title="Pip Threshold")
timeFrame = input("5", title="Time Frame", options=["1", "5", "15", "30", "60", "D"])

maxPrice = security(syminfo.tickerid, timeFrame, high)
minPrice = security(syminfo.tickerid, timeFrame, low)

priceChange = (maxPrice - minPrice) / syminfo.mintick

if priceChange > pipThreshold
    message = "BTC price changed by " + tostring(priceChange) + " pips in " + timeFrame + "-minute(s)."
    alert(message)

plot(priceChange, title="Price Change (Pips)", color=color.blue, linewidth=2) ```
````